# Regex matches online, but not when run

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm having a really strange issue with a regular expression. This is my expression:

`const csrfRegex = /"csrf_token": "((\\"|[^"])*)"/ig;`

The purpose of this is to pull out the CSRF token from a Javascript object on a scraped site. Excerpt of the page is as follows:

```
[...]
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = { "config": {"viewer": null, "csrf_token": "rYzP3AWdRFIoz9UJbyholRAX5QSiirCR"}, "display_properties_server_guess": {"viewport_width": 360, "pixel_ratio": 1.5}, "entry_data": {"LoginAndSignupPage": [{}]}, "platform": "web", "qe": {"discovery": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "us": {"p": {"use_continue_text": "false"}, "g": "continue_vs_signup_text_control_03"}, "ebd": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "gql": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "freq": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "br": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "feed": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "su_universe": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "profile": {"p": {}, "g": ""}, "us_li": {"p": {}, "g": ""}}, "language_code": "en", "environment_switcher_visible_server_guess": true};</script>
[...]
```

If I test it online using Regex101, the first capture group matches it correctly: https://regex101.com/r/zDxPFw/1

However, in my code it is unable to find a match, and returns inside the if statement:

```
let csrf_scrape = csrfRegex.exec(body);

// Both must have a length of at least 2
if (!csrf_scrape || !csrf_scrape.length) {
  console.log(body);
  return next(`No CSRF token found`);
}

let csrf = csrf_scrape[1];
return next(null, csrf);
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: csrf=csrf_scrape[0] ? I think...

Comment: Your main problem is probably the `/g` flag but it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: The `g` modifier cannot be a problem with `RegExp#exec`. I got `rYzP3AWdRFIoz9UJbyholRAX5QSiirCR`, see https://jsfiddle.net/9eLo73os/.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're wrong.

Comment: @melpomene: If I am wrong, why does the code work (finds a match)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because your code is different from what OP used. Just because it works in one case doesn't mean "the `g` modifier cannot be a problem".

Comment: You're using the php version of the regex texter. Try using it with the JavaScript version https://regex101.com/r/zB0gP7/1

Comment: It cannot be a problem here, exec is only run once.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How do you know this?

Comment: Are you sure that data is not bound to page dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, positive. I've also verified that it is the regex causing the issue using `body.indexOf('csrf_token')`, which gives me the position of the start of the token (even when regex finds zero results). I believe the token is a fixed width, so could just substring after that but seems quite hacky.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you need the inner catched group, so this should be enough I imagine:

```
var csrfRegex = /"csrf_token": "((?:\\"|[^"])*)"/i;
```

Using `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. Then you can easily get it this way:

```
var value = text.match(csrfRegex)[1];
```

The `g` flag must be removed for `str.match()` to return the group value.